# How to set sqlalchemy relationship using a list of ids?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm trying to figure out how to update a relationship using a list of foriegn keys.

Take for example the standard parent/children relationship from the SQLAlchemy documentation:

```py
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent_table"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    children: Mapped[list["Child"]] = relationship(back_populates="parent")


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "child_table"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    parent_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("parent_table.id"), nullable=True)
    parent: Mapped["Parent"] = relationship(back_populates="children")
```

The normal relationship modelling means that if I want to update the list of children from the parent I need to have all of those child objects. Instead I'd like to have a property on the `Parent` class that is the id's of the ascociated `Child` classes but can be updated as well.

I've seen this answer: [how to access list of keys for a relationship in SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70034441/how-to-access-list-of-keys-for-a-relationship-in-sqlalchemy) which gives the "read" side of the equation, but how can I write an efficient setter to do the other half?

Note: The children in my scenario already exist. I suspect I need to use the `update_expression` function in order to build a sql query that will go and look for the existing children and link them accross. But I'm not sure if that's right...

This is what I've got so far.

```py
@hybrid_property
def child_ids(self) -> List[uuid.UUID]:
    return [child.id for child in self.children]

@child_ids.expression
def child_ids(self):
    select([Child.id]).where(
        Child.parent_id == self.id
    )

@child_ids.setter
def child_ids(self, value):
    # What here?
    pass
```

For completeness, I'm specifically asking how to do this in the Model using properties/hybrid_properties.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work but I'm not sure how reliable it will be with a lot of simultaneous requests to set child_ids.  If it is a big deal you might get a row lock on the parent to synchronize calls to set child_ids.

- delete and insert differences between `value` and `self.children`
- you need to set delete-orphan cascade or else Child objects end up with `Child(id=5, parent_id=None)` when using s`elf.children.remove(child)`

```py
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    @hybrid_property
    def child_ids(self):
        return [child.id for child in self.children]

    @child_ids.expression
    def child_ids(self):
        return select([Child.id]).where(
            Child.parent_id == self.id
        )

    @child_ids.setter
    def child_ids(self, value):
        """
        Sync children with given children ids.

        value: list[int]
            List of children ids.
        """
        # Child ids in value found in self.children.
        found_child_ids = set()
        # Childs in self.children whose id is not in value.
        to_delete = set()
        for child in self.children:
            if child.id not in value:
                to_delete.add(child)
            else:
                found_child_ids.add(child.id)
        # Delete children not in value.
        for child in to_delete:
            # This only deletes the Child object because we have delete-orphan cascade set.
            self.children.remove(child)
        # Create children with child ids in value that were not found in self.children.
        for child_id in (set(value) - found_child_ids):
            self.children.append(Child(id=child_id, parent_id=self.id))

    children = relationship('Child', back_populates="parent",
                            # Need this to delete orphaned children.
                            cascade="all, delete-orphan")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'childs'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parents.id'))

    parent = relationship('Parent', back_populates="children")

metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session, session.begin():
    p1 = Parent()
    session.add(p1)


with Session(engine) as session:
    p1 = session.get(Parent, 1)

    # Add 1, 5
    p1.child_ids = [1, 5]
    session.commit()

    # Add 2, Remove 1, Leave 5
    p1.child_ids = [2, 5]
    session.commit()

    # Remove 2, Remove 5
    p1.child_ids = []
    session.commit()
```

#### Echo after `create_all`

```
2023-01-17 21:35:51,060 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-01-17 21:35:51,064 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO parents DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING parents.id
2023-01-17 21:35:51,065 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00058s] {}
2023-01-17 21:35:51,067 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2023-01-17 21:35:51,104 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-01-17 21:35:51,106 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT parents.id AS parents_id 
FROM parents 
WHERE parents.id = %(pk_1)s
2023-01-17 21:35:51,106 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00021s] {'pk_1': 1}
2023-01-17 21:35:51,109 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT childs.id AS childs_id, childs.parent_id AS childs_parent_id 
FROM childs 
WHERE %(param_1)s = childs.parent_id
2023-01-17 21:35:51,110 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00017s] {'param_1': 1}
2023-01-17 21:35:51,112 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO childs (id, parent_id) VALUES (%(id)s, %(parent_id)s)
2023-01-17 21:35:51,112 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00017s] ({'id': 1, 'parent_id': 1}, {'id': 5, 'parent_id': 1})
2023-01-17 21:35:51,114 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2023-01-17 21:35:51,163 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-01-17 21:35:51,165 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT parents.id AS parents_id 
FROM parents 
WHERE parents.id = %(pk_1)s
2023-01-17 21:35:51,165 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00025s] {'pk_1': 1}
2023-01-17 21:35:51,166 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT childs.id AS childs_id, childs.parent_id AS childs_parent_id 
FROM childs 
WHERE %(param_1)s = childs.parent_id
2023-01-17 21:35:51,166 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 0.05671s ago] {'param_1': 1}
2023-01-17 21:35:51,168 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO childs (id, parent_id) VALUES (%(id)s, %(parent_id)s)
2023-01-17 21:35:51,168 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00017s] {'id': 2, 'parent_id': 1}
2023-01-17 21:35:51,170 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine DELETE FROM childs WHERE childs.id = %(id)s
2023-01-17 21:35:51,170 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00015s] {'id': 1}
2023-01-17 21:35:51,170 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2023-01-17 21:35:51,204 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-01-17 21:35:51,206 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT parents.id AS parents_id 
FROM parents 
WHERE parents.id = %(pk_1)s
2023-01-17 21:35:51,206 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 0.04138s ago] {'pk_1': 1}
2023-01-17 21:35:51,208 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT childs.id AS childs_id, childs.parent_id AS childs_parent_id 
FROM childs 
WHERE %(param_1)s = childs.parent_id
2023-01-17 21:35:51,209 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 0.09924s ago] {'param_1': 1}
2023-01-17 21:35:51,211 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine DELETE FROM childs WHERE childs.id = %(id)s
2023-01-17 21:35:51,211 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00025s] ({'id': 2}, {'id': 5})
2023-01-17 21:35:51,212 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Ian, unfortunately in my scenario, the Children already exist so I can't just create and delete them. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: I guess I don't fully understand the model.  Is it one too many? And also if a child is orphaned should the parent ID just be set to null?

Comment: Additionally, can a child change from one parent to a different parent?

Comment: Hey Ian, yes to both your questions. Children can exist without parents and can move from one to another (in reality it's actually a many to many join with an ascociation table, so a child can actually have multiple parents but I figured asking the basic case would simplify things)

Comment: If you used an AssocationObject I think it would be the same as my example, like here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object